# loading external jar files in solr-5.3.1

Tags: java, solr, solrj, solrcloud

I've switched my solr version from 4.3.0 to 5.3.1.
I want to know ,how to load an external jar file(for example my customized analyzer) and use it as anlyzer of a field?
I used to add `<lib>` tag in solrconfig.xml in 4.3.0 and everything was working just fine.

example:
`<lib dir="../../../contrib/analysis-extras/extra-libs" regex=".*\.jar" />`
But now when I'm trying to do the same in 5.3.1 it doesn't work and it gives me this error: "Cannot load analyzer"
however in solr 5.3.1 It seems that it changed the way of loading jar files.
Can anybody help me on this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `sharedLib` parameter into the [solr.xml](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Format+of+solr.xml) file.

I have already written something about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897412/adding-my-own-classes-to-solr-5-3-1/34911600#34911600).