# Adding my own classes to solr 5.3.1

Tags: solr, solrj

I want to update my solr based application from Solr 4 to Solr 5.3.1

I just found out, since Solr 5.2 it is no longer possible to run Solr as a WebApp.
So instead of packaging the project (with solr as Maven dependencies) as a WAR and running it with a separate Jetty, now I need to put my source code into the Solr.
But how can i do this?

I tried to package my project as a JAR and put it in the folder `/solr-5.3.1/contrib/mySearchApplication/lib/mysearch.jar` and I added this path in solrconfig.xml `<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/mySearchApplication/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />` but when I try to run Solr it still can't find my Classes, e.g. my customized token filters.

So how can I add my java classes to solr?

I get this error message:

`ERROR (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   ] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Error creating core [myCollection]: Could not load conf for core myCollection: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "text_en": Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter: Error loading class 'com.mySearchApplication.lucene.analysis.pattern.SplitOnPatternFilterFactory'. Schema file is /var/tmp/solr/myCollection/conf/schema.xml
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core myCollection: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "text_en": Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter: Error loading class 'com.mySearchApplication.lucene.analysis.pattern.SplitOnPatternFilterFactory'. Schema file is /var/tmp/solr/myCollection/conf/schema.xml
    at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.getConfig(ConfigSetService.java:80)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:721)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:443)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:434)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor$1.run(ExecutorUtil.java:210)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "text_en": Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter: Error loading class 'com.mySearchApplication.lucene.analysis.pattern.SplitOnPatternFilterFactory'. Schema file is /var/tmp/solr/myCollection/conf/schema.xml
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:596)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.<init>(IndexSchema.java:175)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchemaFactory.create(IndexSchemaFactory.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchemaFactory.buildIndexSchema(IndexSchemaFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.createIndexSchema(ConfigSetService.java:104)
    at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.getConfig(ConfigSetService.java:75)
    ... 8 more`

Comment: possible your path is wrong. Copy your lib folder in same parent-folder as `solrconfig.xml` and use `dir="lib"`: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Lib+Directives+in+SolrConfig

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried, but I still get:
`org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core myCollection: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "text_en": Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter: Error loading class 'com.mySearchApplication.lucene.analysis.pattern.SplitOnPatternFilterFactory'. Schema file is /var/tmp/solr/myCollection/conf/schema.xml`

Comment: Please copy and rename an existing filter to your jar-file and try to access it form solr. Possible your "SplitOnPatternFilterFactory"-Class has a problem with a static constructor? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352215/java-why-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-caused-by-static-field-initializ-failur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `sharedLib` parameter into the [solr.xml](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Format+of+solr.xml) file.

> This parameter specifies the path to a common library directory that
>   will be shared across all cores. Any JAR files in this directory will
>   be added to the search path for Solr plugins. This path is relative to
>   the top-level container's Solr Home.

Here is how I did.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<solr>
      <str name='sharedLib'>/opt/shared-lib</str>

      <solrcloud>
          <str name="host">${host:}</str>
          <int name="hostPort">${hostPort:8080}</int>
          <str name="hostContext">${hostContext:solr}</str>
          <int name="zkClientTimeout">${zkClientTimeout:15000}</int>
          <bool name="genericCoreNodeNames">${genericCoreNodeNames:true}</bool>
      </solrcloud>

      <shardHandlerFactory name="shardHandlerFactory"
          class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
          <int name="socketTimeout">${socketTimeout:0}</int>
          <int name="connTimeout">${connTimeout:0}</int>
      </shardHandlerFactory>

</solr>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when i try this i get: 
`java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.authenticateRequest(SolrDispatchFilter.java:241)
 at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:186)
 at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:179)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)`

Comment: after fixing a syntax error, I still get:
`org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core myCollection: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "text_en": Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter: Error loading class 'com.mySearchApplication.lucene.analysis.pattern.SplitOnPatternFilterFactory'. Schema file is /var/tmp/solr/myCollection/conf/schema.xml`

any idea what I could try?

Comment: Try using absolute path when specifying where are your libraries. And be sure all dependencies are satisfied.

Comment: To get this answer working for me I needed to change it to an absolute path. `<str name="sharedLib">${solr.install.dir}/opt/shared-lib</str>`

Answer (score 0):

In Windows solr.xml may look like this:

```
<solr>
  <str name='sharedLib'>F:\solr_deployment\solr-7.6.0\contrib\analysis-extras\lucene-libs</str>

  <solrcloud>

    <str name="host">${host:}</str>
    <int name="hostPort">${jetty.port:8983}</int>
    <str name="hostContext">${hostContext:solr}</str>

    <bool name="genericCoreNodeNames">${genericCoreNodeNames:true}</bool>

    <int name="zkClientTimeout">${zkClientTimeout:30000}</int>
    <int name="distribUpdateSoTimeout">${distribUpdateSoTimeout:600000}</int>
    <int name="distribUpdateConnTimeout">${distribUpdateConnTimeout:60000}</int>
    <str name="zkCredentialsProvider">${zkCredentialsProvider:org.apache.solr.common.cloud.DefaultZkCredentialsProvider}</str>
    <str name="zkACLProvider">${zkACLProvider:org.apache.solr.common.cloud.DefaultZkACLProvider}</str>

  </solrcloud>

  <shardHandlerFactory name="shardHandlerFactory"
    class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
    <int name="socketTimeout">${socketTimeout:600000}</int>
    <int name="connTimeout">${connTimeout:60000}</int>
  </shardHandlerFactory>

</solr>
```

Alternatively, one may have this in solrconfig.xml file:

```
<config>
        <luceneMatchVersion>7.6.0</luceneMatchVersion>

        <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
        <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />

        <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/clustering/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
        <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-clustering-\d.*\.jar" />

        <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/langid/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
        <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-langid-\d.*\.jar" />

        <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/velocity/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
        <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-velocity-\d.*\.jar" />

        <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/analysis-extras/lucene-libs" regex=".*\.jar" />
        <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-analysis-\d.*\.jar" />
...
</config>
```